# Untracked Changes on Server - How to Sync with Origin

Tags: git, github

On one of our websites, we've been using Git only to track changes on local copies, then deploying the changes to our live server using Deploy HQ. I was not expecting any changes to be made directly on the live server, so I did not have a Git repo set up on there.

However, someone updated the CMS version directly on the server, so now our server has a bunch of untracked changes.

I now have two goals:

1. Set up a repo on the server to track these changes
2. Sync up my origin in GitHub with these changes

Aside from the technicalities of setting up Git on the server, I'm wondering how to add the files on the server to an existing repository, even though they have new untracked changes (that we want to keep).

- Can I just place the .git and .gitignore files from my local repository onto the server?
- Will that recognize the new changes that happened as changes that need to be committed?

Once I get the repo properly set up there, I am assuming I can just push the changes out to Origin in GitHub.

Comment: It's not making sense, what are you trying to achieve actually? You have untracked changes on the server, so are you trying to keep and push those changes to the origin, which I think is github? Or do you want to sync it with the origin, this means those untracked changes on the server will be lost as the origin don't probably have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get out of that mess pretty easily:

- On your development repository, check out the branch or tag of your last known deploy to that server:

  ```
  git reset --hard   # careful, will throw away any previous changes
  git checkout currently_deployed_version
  ```

  Your own repository is now exactly like the server should have been, unless someone had modified the server files directly. Obviously, instead of the `reset`, you can just commit or stash the stuff you are working on right now.
- Copy your server files straight over:

  ```
  rsync -a user@server:/path_to_installation/* path_to_your_existing_repo/
  ```

  It is not important which tool you use; if you do not have `rsync`, you can use `scp` or, if you are on Windows, any other similar tool.
- Voilá: you now get your diffs for free

  ```
  git diff
  ```

  It will show you directly what the changes where. You can go on from here as usual; commit, revert/checkout; modify as needed; push to whatever appropriate branch etc.
- After cleaning everything up, you can deploy again; this time including a `.git` directory. Make it one with depth 0 (see `git help clone`) to avoid lots of junk on the server; that will be enough to give you serverside `git diff` later, which in turn is enough to create a patch file for transporting changes back to the development machine in a sane(r) way.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Deploy HQ, but is not it telling you which files changed and which commit was deployed as last? You should be able to get those files to your working dir, commit and push.

Also IIUC the Deploy HQ may create additional files as result of scripted actions. Simply ignore these unless these changes were made to generated output. In such case git will not help you in merging the changes and you will have to result to reverse engineering the changes anyway. It would still be helpful in reviewing diffs.

Copying .git from another working copy would do the trick. However, make sure the same commit as the one which was last deployed is checked out, or you will see way too many changes. I guess Deploy HQ logs should be able to tell you which commit was deployed. But you can find the commit on the branch by doing `git reset $COMMIT` and checking the diff. Depending on number of commits this may be tedious.

After finding the correct base commit and committing the changes on the server, you can pull working dir from the server to your machine and push to github.

Also there is a possible caveat. Git history may be publicly visible and if that contains any accidentally committed sensitive information those will be accessible to an attacker. In that case you could create .git in different directory, and set GIT_DIR and GIT_WORK_TREE variables. But as you said the repo is already accessible on github so that is likely not a problem.